# C# - Collection is enough or comobination of LINQ will improve performance?

Tags: c#

According to the requirement we have to return a collection either in reverse order or as

it is. We, beginning level programmer designed the collection as follow :(sample is given)

```
namespace Linqfying

{

 class linqy

  {
      static void Main()

      {

         InvestigationReport rpt=new InvestigationReport();

         // rpt.GetDocuments(true) refers 
        //  to return the collection in reverse order       


            foreach(  EnquiryDocument doc in rpt.GetDocuments(true)   )
            {

               // printing document title and author name     

             }
        }
  } 




 class EnquiryDocument

  {
       string _docTitle;

       string _docAuthor;

       // properties to get and set doc title and author name goes below 


      public EnquiryDocument(string title,string author)

      {
      _docAuthor = author;

      _docTitle = title;
      }

      public EnquiryDocument(){}

}



   class InvestigationReport

   {

       EnquiryDocument[] docs=new EnquiryDocument[3];

      public IEnumerable<EnquiryDocument> GetDocuments(bool IsReverseOrder)

       {

           /* some business logic to retrieve the document 

            docs[0]=new EnquiryDocument("FundAbuse","Margon");

          docs[1]=new EnquiryDocument("Sexual Harassment","Philliphe");

              docs[2]=new EnquiryDocument("Missing Resource","Goel"); 

         */ 


         //if reverse order is preferred

          if(IsReverseOrder)
          {

              for (int i = docs.Length; i != 0; i--)
              yield return docs[i-1];

          }

         else
          {
            foreach (EnquiryDocument doc in docs)
        {
             yield return doc;
            }
      }

      } 

}

 }
```

---

Question :

- *Can we use other collection type to improve efficiency ?*
- *Mixing of Collection with LINQ reduce the code ? (We are not familiar with LINQ)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me. Yes, you could use the `Reverse` extension method... but that won't be as efficient as what you've got.

How much do you care about the efficiency though? I'd go with the most *readable* solution (namely `Reverse`) until you know that efficiency is a problem. Unless the collection is large, it's unlikely to be an issue.

If you've got the "raw data" as an array, then your use of an iterator block will be more efficient than calling `Reverse`. The `Reverse` method will buffer up all the data before yielding it one item at a time - just like your own code does, really. However, simply calling `Reverse` would be a lot simpler...

Aside from anything else, I'd say it's well worth you learning LINQ - at least LINQ to Objects. It can make processing data *much, much* cleaner than before.

Comment: our project lead just threw a command as "even during his school days he did not develop such a bad line of coding".We got shocked ,that is the reason we posted this.Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Two questions:

1. Does the code you currently have work?
2. Have you identified this piece of code as being your performance bottleneck?

If the answer to either of those questions is no, don't worry about it. Just make it work and move on. There's nothing grossly wrong about the code, so no need to fret! Spend your time building new functionality instead. Save LINQ for a new problem you haven't already solved.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this task seems pretty straightforward.  I'd actually just use the [Reverse method on a Generic List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c6526tb.aspx).

This should already be well-optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Your GetDocuments method has a return type of IEnumerable so there is no need to even loop over your array when IsReverseOrder is false, you can just return it as is as Array type is IEnumerable...

As for when IsReverseOrder is true you can use either Array.Reverse or the Linq Reverse() extension method to reduce the amount of code.